# How to throw error from start-up powershell script to google deployment manager in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am creating a windows 2016 instance using deployment manager in GCP. Also I am running a start-script on the instance which is in powershell.

I want to throw the error and stop the execution if my powershell script fails on the instance created by deployment manager with some generic error.

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Can you specify what your script is supposed to to ? If you can please post it here and we'll try to figure out the solution from there.

Comment: @Wojtek_B it is a configuration script, which configures some registry values as per my application requirements and restarts application services. That's it.

Comment: @Wojtek_B after searching on this I found that waiters is the mechanism for this for deployment manager. Now here I want more information on handling failure conditions on waiters. [waiters](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/creating-a-waiter)

Answer (score 1):

The deployment manager API does not go into your GCE instance so a direct integration won't work. The DM API is calling the GCE API and will consider the instance created once the GCE API returns the appropriate status. For this to fail automatically, your instance creation will need to fail if the powershell script fails. I don't see this as terribly feasible since the GCE infrastructure is basically in place by the time the script starts running.

Alternatively, you can tweak your script. If the script encounters an error, it should trigger a [deployment stop API call](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deployment-manager/deployments/stop) to the DM API. There will be a delay here though. If you are only creating the instance, the deployment will be considered completed before your powershell has a chance to run, fail, and make the API call.